# SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired while calling an sql query and add the results to the list

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm trying to call a SQL query from dashboard and add them to list.

My current code is:

```
var ambulances = db.Ambulances.Include(a => a.Station)
                              .Include(a => a.Calls)
                              .Where(a => a.ambulance_active == true);

DashboardVM dashboardVM = new DashboardVM();
dashboardVM.ambulances = ambulances.ToList();
```

On the last line of my code while running I get the following error:

> SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I tried the same SQL in the database and it's working properly.

Comment: Did you try reading the error message? Did you try researching it?

Comment: @IanKemp I did with no luck. Can you help me please?

Comment: One thing you can do is Use SQL Server Management Studio and use XEvent profiler to look a the SQL that being generated. Do the databases have a lot of data?

Comment: @ChrisCatignani Yes, it returns around ~70.000 records.

Comment: 70K is not necessarily a whole lot...relatively speaking. Double check with you tech guy and see how much memory is on that server...and what else may be running on that box. You are pulling in redundant Station data for every Call also.